# testfixtures.StringComparison does not allow regex flags

Tags: regex, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to capture logs for testing purpose and matching it through regex using `testfixtures` module from python for that and doing logging through `logging` module.

Here's the replica of what is actually happening essentially:

```
import logging, traceback
from testfixtures import LogCapture, StringComparison

exception = None
try:
    raise Exception('test exception')
except Exception as ex:
    exception = ex

traceback_str = '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(type(exception), exception, exception.__traceback__))

with LogCapture() as capture:
    logging.info(traceback_str)
capture.check(('root', 'INFO', StringComparison(r'.*test exception.*')))
```

But this code gives error and does not match. And I'm not able to put `re.DOTALL` flag to consider `.` in regex as new line character also, as it is giving error on number of parameters of `StringComparison`.

Right now, as a workaround, I'm using the following regex:

```
capture.check(('root', 'INFO', StringComparison(r'(.*\n)*.*test exception.*'))
```

Is there any other way of providing flags to compare captured logs, or check logs using different function ?

Comment: That's a third party module, not part of the standard library; if you think it needs a new feature, raise it with the maintainers

Comment: Doesn't `r'(?s).*test exception.*'` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use *inline modifier* version `(?s)` that is equal to passing a `re.DOTALL` / `re.S` flags to the regex engine:

```
r'(?s).*test exception.*'
```

See `re` documentation:

> **`(?aiLmsux)`**
>   (One or more letters from the set `'a'`, `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'u'`, `'x'`.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: [re.A](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.A) (ASCII-only matching), [re.I](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.I) (ignore case), [re.L](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.L) (locale dependent), [re.M](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.M) (multi-line), [re.S](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.S) (dot matches all), and [re.X](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.X) (verbose), for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in [*Module Contents*](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re).) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a *flag* argument to the [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.compile) function.